# Showing that $x^4 + x^3 + 31x^2 + 130x + 107$ is irreducible

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

I need to prove that 
$$x^4 + x^3 + 31x^2 + 130x + 107$$
is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ using the Eisenstein criterion for $p=7$ and that $f(x)$ is irreducible if $f(x+c)$ is irreducible. I have tried some values for $c=1,2,3,4$, but that doesnt seem to work since $c^4+c^3+31c^2+130c+107$ is not divisible by $7$. My approach was just to try out some values for $c$. Is there a better way to look for values for $c$ that work?

Comment: How can you use Eisenstein for $p=7$? None of the coefficient is divisible by $7$.

Comment: We are to use Eisenstein on f(x+c) not f(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If positive doesn't work try negative. $c=-2\implies f(-2)=-21.$ And 
$$
f(x-2)=x^4-7x^3+49x^2-14x-21
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think I actually tried c=-2. Probably messed up my calculation